# Code Signing "ClientSideInteractiveMediaAds.framework" failed for tvOS when try to upload build to Store

Tags: ads, tvos

I am using Google ClientSide IMA SDK for Video ads. But after using that I am not able to upload builds to Store. Its shows error message Code Signing "ClientSideInteractiveMediaAds.framework" failed. Anyone facing same issue[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked on adding the script mentioned in the below link in run Scripts

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-tvos-dai/tree/master/scripts